# ARM M4 branches to unreadable address immediately after reset

Tags: arm, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

I'm working on a project on a Silicon Labs Thunderboard React (RD0057) which has a EFR32BG1xxxF256 processor on it (Cortex M4).

Recently when I went to program the board and debug, the code immediately goes to a hard fault before entering main. (IACCVIOL and STKERR both set).

I've:

- Reverted the code to a previous version I know compiled and ran
- Tried another board I have
- Used the J-Link adapter to fully erase the flash and reprogram it
- Tried an empty example project

All to the same result

I then stepped through the code and saw that just after reset the code:

- starting at address 0xf210000
- some random seemingly unrelated stuff (4 lines)
- loads R3 with 0x4
- loads R2 with R3 (after executing this R2 shows 0xFFFFF in debugger)
- bx R2 (which branches to ffffffe0, which says "Fail to read memory" and triggers the hard fault)

Tools:
 - Thunderboard React RD0057
 - WSTK 4001A Rev A01 (Functioning as J-Link adapter)
 - Simplicity Studio
 - Bluetooth SDK 2.10.1

I need to work out a way to post my code later tonight, but does this issue sound familiar to anyone? I'm thinking it might not be code related because it's happened in known good versions of the project and in empty example projects. Any help is appreciated.

Update 1:

[Pastebin of Start of Binary](https://pastebin.com/Sms8fHiW), excerpt first three entries:

```
007c 0020 4da0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000 49a0 0000
```

I checked the binary as suggested, and the first few entries appear to be a vector table (bunch of 0x49A0 which I believe translates to loading addresses into registers).

Then I used the J-link "J-Mem" to read out the memory of the chip. This showed all 0xFFFF's after programming the chip with the IDE (blank chip). I then used the J-Link command line utility to flash the binary file with the start address set to 0x00. Then read back the memory again, and this appears to be successful, with the contents matching the bin file. Executing this shows me getting past that first load and branch that caused the hard fault before, but now hitting another hard fault elsewhere.

- Need to determine why the IDE is unsuccessful at programming code. Assuming something is set wrong with an offset because it seems to be missing the flash address range altogether.
- Need to determine where this new hard fault is occurring and if it's the fault of my code or another weird thing.

Comment: yes and just asked this week...start off by posting the first few words of your binary/memory image, not the bytes of the elf file but the first few words that will end up in flash.

Comment: is there a demo binary from vendor or somewhere that works?  you can load it and examine what you see and or use the same hex dump tools and see what you see.  the zeros being there that isnt an instruction that looks like vectors sram starts at 0x20000000 so that looks like it wants to be 0x20007c00 and if that is the case with a byteswap then the address is 0x00000a4d which would be a valid address.   are you able to disassemble the binary (usually an elf file format not bin works best)?

Comment: 00004da0  andeq r4, r0, r0, lsr #27

Comment: thats some sort of vector not a bunch of sane instructions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the gnu binutils built for arm/thumb, take this:

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang
.word hang
.thumb_func
reset:
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    b reset
.thumb_func
hang:   b .
```

build it:

```
arm-none-eabi-as flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0 flash.o -o flash.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D flash.elf > flash.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy flash.elf -O binary flash.bin
```

It doesn't have to be arm-none-eabi; it can be arm-linux-gnueabi or whatever arm-something-something.

Examine the list file; this is what you are looking for to boot a cortex-m.

```
00000000 <_start>:
   0:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
   4:   00000015    andeq   r0, r0, r5, lsl r0
   8:   00000021    andeq   r0, r0, r1, lsr #32
   c:   00000021    andeq   r0, r0, r1, lsr #32
  10:   00000021    andeq   r0, r0, r1, lsr #32

00000014 <reset>:
  14:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  16:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  18:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  1a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  1c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  1e:   e7f9        b.n 14 <reset>

00000020 <hang>:
  20:   e7fe        b.n 20 <hang>
```

First word in flash gets loaded into the stack pointer for you, you can change the stack pointer in your bootstrap code if you want, this just saves a step.  The address for reset orred with a 1 is next, has to have the lsbit set.  Reset is at 0x0014 above so the reset vector needs to have 0x0014|1 = 0x0015.

The rest of the vectors don't matter to get you booted.  This one puts it in a simple infinite loop which you can halt and resume with your debugger and find it at different addresses hopefully as you repeat halt and resume.

It is probably easier to load the elf file than the bin file with a debugger, but at the same time the tool might not be writing to flash correctly. Use the tool to dump a few words starting at 0x00000000.

If your binary does not start with a vector table and/or if the vector table has even numbered addresses in it you will go off the rails immediately after reset. If it does, then you would need to dig further.

Comment: Hey @old_timer, thanks for your response. I've added some more info to the original post that you requested before I stop for the night.
Where exactly would I find the disassembly of the program (is this assembly code or original C?) . I assume what I posted is the vector table, where would the reset code be? Is that also in the hex and if so how do I locate?

Sorry for all the questions, I really appreciate the help and want to make sure I get you the right info.

Comment: what toolchain are you using is there an arm-something-objdump in your path?  do you have a file other than one that is a .bin type memory image one that has ELF in the first few bytes 0x45 0x4c 0x46?  with binutils which you can probably find you can disassemble with that arm-whatever-objdump -D myprog.elf although it probably doesnt have a .elf extension.   do you have source code for the bootstrap this is most likely assembly language but sometimes they do inline assembly in C...

Comment: I am using the SiLabs IDE which uses arm-none-eabi, and was able to disassemble my program and confirm the vector table was good. After confirming that the file looked good, I did as you suggested and flashed the chip and then dumped its memory to confirm flashing was successful, which is where I found the problem (not flashing correctly). Unfortunately, the solution I found wasn't very satisfying, I just wiped my IDE and reinstalled it which fixed whatever issue I was having in the toolchain. I will accept your answer since it provided good steps for debugging this issue.

Comment: yeah, thats part of it. often the fails immediately is the vector table.  but not even writing the right stuff to flash is even before that, when you have jtag tools like this you can examine what you wrote to see that it matches.  glad you persisted and won...now you can do fun stuff...

Comment: Its pretty nice! And a good price too. The demo app provided by SL has a pretty solid interface already developed for every sensor on the board too so it's pretty easy to hack something together quickly. I'd recommend it.